# What is the difference between Console.Write(5/2) and Console.Write(5.0/2)?

Tags: c#, console.writeline

When in a "challenge" in the app sololearn, answering C# related questions against each other, the question was "Are the outputs below going to be the same?"

```
Console.Write(5 / 2 + 2.5); // 4.5
Console.Write(5.0 / 2 + 2.5); // 5
```

When I run it it indeed gets different results (shown as comments in the code). Why the outputs of below is not the same?

Comment: I will not give you the answer but here is a hint. 5.0.GetType().Name, 5.GetType().Name I am pretty sure you will be able to figure it out on you own from there

Answer (score 2):

In case of: `Console.Write(5 / 2 + 2.5);`
The 5 / 2 is considered as integer/integer division. Check out this code:

```
    int i = 5;
    int j = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(i / j);
    //prints 2
```

In case of: `Console.Write(5.0 / 2 + 2.5);`
The 5.0 / 2 is considered as double/integer division. Same code would be:

```
     double i = 5.0;
     int j = 2;
     Console.WriteLine(i / j);
     //prints 2.5
```

*So in your case 5/2 + 2.5 results to 2 + 2.5 => 4.5*

*But in 5.0/2 + 2.5 we get 2.5 + 2.5 => 5*